# element attribute of form:checkboxes in Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Im having a hard time making a **element attribute of form:checkboxes work for 
css class .row-fluid1**

The JSP code is

```
<h:field path="configuredChannels" required="true"
                        code="admin.menu.channels">
                        <div class="row-fluid" data-channel-checkboxes="#" style="row-fluid1">
                            <form:checkboxes element="div class='span1 row-fluid1'" 
                                items="${channels}" path="configuredChannels" />
                        </div>
</h:field>
```

and the CSS code is

```
<style type="text/css">
.row-fluid1 [class*=span]
{display:block;
width:100%;
min-height:30px;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
float:left;
margin-left:3.4482758620689653%;
}
</style>
```

Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: What should it do that it doesn't? Judging from the code you have also created your own custom-tag lib, does that work properly? Have you included all the needed JS files in your project?

Comment: it should align the spacing between the checkboxes and the channel list , yes I have created a custom tag lib which works perfectly

Comment: But what should it do?! What I see is that your element attribute isn't closed properly.

Comment: Can you post/add the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:field path="configuredChannels" required="true" code="admin.menu.channels">
    <div class="row-fluid" data-channel-checkboxes="#" style="row-fluid1">
        <form:checkboxes element="div" cssClass="span1 row-fluid1" items="${channels}" path="configuredChannels" />
    </div>
</h:field>
```

I would expect something like the above to work. You also have a div inside a div, which (if I recall correctly) with bootstrap (due to the row) adds a padding/margin on the left/right.